# Most efficient way of creating a progress bar while reading input from a file

Tags: c++

I have a program which is reading in input from a relatively large file, thousands of lines long.

With that being said, I want to implement a progress bar indicator while the file is being processed. However, most methods I'm aware of require you to use `getLine` to count how many lines there are in the file to use this as the "predefined goal" for your progress bar [(Boost Example)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/timer/doc/original_timer.html#Class%20progress_display). That means I'd have to loop through a large text file twice, once to count how many lines, and another to actually get each line and display a progress bar.

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: This is why most progress bars don't actually represent progress. They're just guesses to show the user that progress is being made.

Comment: I see. Maybe a fair compromise would be something like appending a `.` to a output after processing each line. But I must admit, a progress bar looks pretty sexy even if it is a rough guesstimate.

Comment: You can read a million lines in a few seconds. Unless your processing is really intensive you may not need this thing at all. Or else you can just compute the progress in terms of bytes rather than lines.

Comment: do it by byte count, not line count.  unless you're reading from a pipe you can get that.

Comment: You could also read in the file and store the lines in memory (if it's small), then base your progress count off that.

Comment: sure, have the line count at the start of the file. Barring that, line count is just the number of `\n`s you have (or `\r\n` for windows). The only way to count those is to look at everything in the file.

Comment: If this is for ASCII-art bars it's a pretty moot point anyway, your resolution is only a few chars and there probably isn't a defined end point. Just decide that each char represents some number of lines read, and increment it as you process.

Comment: Another possibility is to seek to the end of the file, just to learn the size of the input. Then, divide the size by 10, or 100, and keep increasing your progress bar as you check the current position from which you're reading the file. This should give you a very nice and simple progress bar -- which may be prettified with ASCII-art and carriage returns (`\r`).

Comment: Lots of good information and suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: @Rubens: why not posting your valid and valuable answer?

Comment: @NirMH Thanks for the very kind suggestion. I've added an answer with a sample implementation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A possible solution is to seek to the end of the file, just to learn the size of the input. Then, keep updating a progress bar based on the percentage of the file you have already processed. This should give you a very nice and simple progress bar -- which may be prettified with ASCII-art and carriage returns (\r).

Here is also a possible implementation:

```
# include <cmath>
# include <string>
# include <fstream>
# include <iomanip>
# include <iostream>


class reader : public std::ifstream {

public:

    // Constructor
    template <class... Args>
    inline reader(int max, Args&&... args) :
    std::ifstream(args...), _max(max), _last(0) {
        if (std::ifstream::is_open()) _measure();
    }

    // Opens the file and measures its length
    template <class... Args>
    inline auto open(Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(std::ifstream::open(args...)) {
        auto rvalue(std::ifstream::open(args...));
        if (std::ifstream::is_open()) _measure();
        return rvalue;
    }

    // Displays the progress bar (pos == -1 -> end of file)
    inline void drawbar(void) {

        int pos(std::ifstream::tellg());
        float prog(pos / float(_length)); // percentage of infile already read
        if (pos == -1) { _print(_max + 1, 1); return; }

        // Number of #'s as function of current progress "prog"
        int cur(std::ceil(prog * _max));
        if (_last != cur) _last = cur, _print(cur, prog);

    }

private:

    std::string _inpath;
    int _max, _length, _last;

    // Measures the length of the input file
    inline void _measure(void) {
        std::ifstream::seekg(0, end);
        _length = std::ifstream::tellg();
        std::ifstream::seekg(0, beg);
    }

    // Prints out the progress bar
    inline void _print(int cur, float prog) {

        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
            << "\r   [" << std::string(cur, '#')
            << std::string(_max + 1 - cur, ' ') << "] " << 100 * prog << "%";

        if (prog == 1) std::cout << std::endl;
        else std::cout.flush();

    }

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // Creating reader with display of length 100 (100 #'s)
    reader infile(std::atoi(argv[2]), argv[1]);
    std::cout << "-- reading file \"" << argv[1] << "\"" << std::endl;

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(infile, line)) infile.drawbar();

}
```

And the output is something like:

```
$ ./reader foo.txt 50              # ./reader <inpath> <num_#'s>
-- reading file "foo.txt"
   [###################################################] 100.00%
```

Notice the parameters are the input file and the number of #'s you want in your progress bar. I've added the *length-seek* to `std::ifstream::open` function, but the `drawbar()` is called by the user. You may jam this function inside a specific function from `std::ifstream`.

If you want to get it fancier, you could as well use the command `tput cols`, to learn the number of columns in your current shell. Also, you may put such command inside the executable, to make it *clearer* than this:

```
$ ./reader foo.txt $(( $(tput cols) - 30 ))
-- reading file "foo.txt"
   [####################################################################] 100.00%
```

As others pointed, this solution does not work properly with pipes and temporary files, in which cases you don't have the input length at hand. Many thanks @NirMH, for the very kind comment.

Comment: Can you please provide a non O.O.P solution. Thanks