# Display progress in QProgressBar

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QProgress to display the status of reading the configuration file. I have a class that emit a signal to the main window to display the status. Currently, I can display the status but it immediately displays 100%, I want it to be more reliable. Like I can see it progressing for example from 0 to 5 to 20 to 45 and so on until it reached 100%. Here what I've dine so far:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new 
Ui::MainWindow)
{
    connect(sampleClass, SIGNAL(onDisplayStatus(int)), this, 
    SLOT(onDisplayStatus(int)));

    // OtherClass instance
    // config file has lots of fields to be read
    otherClass->validateConfigfile();
}

MainWindow::onDisplayStatus(int status)
{
    ui->ProgressStatus.setValue(status);
}

SampleClass::displayStatus(int value)
{
    emit onDisplayStatus(value);
}

// This will validate if the config file is valid or existing; the 
// progress will be set to 10 if valid and existing
OtherClass::validateConfigfile() 
{
    // instance of SampleClass
    //10 is the value of progress. 
    //I dont want it to be fixed. Pleas suggest how to properly compute 
    //the value
    sampleClassInstance->displayStatus(10); 

    loadSection1();
    loadSection2();
}

OtherClass::loadSection1()
{
    // load section 1 here
    sampleClassInstance->displayStatus(20);
}

OtherClass::loadSection2()
{
    // load section 2 here
    sampleClassInstance->displayStatus(35);
}
```

Note: My config file consists of many fields. Below is the example:

```
[Section 1]
S1Field1 = 0
S1Field2 = 1
S1Field3 = 2

[Section 2]
S2Field1 = 0
S2Field2 = 1

[Section 3]
S3Field1 = 0
S3Field2 = 1
S3Field3 = 2
S3Field4 = 6
S3Field5 = 4
S3Field6 = 9
```

and so on...

I created a method inside OtherClass that will read each section and field. The progress value will be displayed once each section has been read until the progress reached 100.

Comment: are you reading the file line by line?

Comment: Yes, I'm reading the file line by line

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html

You have to set the maximum and minimum of the progressbar.

Comment: Yes it's true. I thought he wants a custom one. 
He said that it jump immetiadly to 100% when he set it to 10, maybe he set a wrong range. @user123456 please show more code.

Comment: I guess that user123456 actually needs a file reading method the computes the progress depending on the file size or something like that. But the question really isn't clear!

Comment: @BenjaminBihler yes you are right. I actually need something like that and update the progress bar depending on the file size.

Comment: @user123456 The progress evaluation is independent from displaying the progress with a QProgressBar, therefore your question is a little bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing in the main thread (the thread of Qt GUI), your widget will not get updated/repainted until you are done, and then directly shows 100%.

In order to use the progressbar correctly you need to process some code in a different process or some asynchronous code.

PS: you could also directly connect your worker class signal to the progressbar slot, you don't need `MainWindow::onDisplayStatus(int status)`.

Comment: Another (somewhat problematic but workable) solution would be for the processing routine in the main thread to periodically call `qApp->processEvents()`

Comment: @ymoreau could you please give me an example?

Comment: It really depends on what you have to process, IO, computation... There are many different ways of being asynchronous. Just keep in mind you should not keep the main thread busy. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html or as Jeremy said https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents

Comment: I tried to create a simple for loop just to see if the progress bar will increment the value. What happen is that it immediately display 100%. I cannot see it incrementing.

for(int i = 0; i <=100; i++){ emit valueChanged(i); qApp->processEvents(QEventloops::ExcludeUserInputEvents); }

Answer (score 0):

You first have to compute the progress while reading the file. Perhaps [Most efficient way of creating a progress bar while reading input from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400933/most-efficient-way-of-creating-a-progress-bar-while-reading-input-from-a-file) might help you.

Then you have to report the progress to a `QProgressBar`. For that your file reading method needs to receive a progress indicator as a function parameter and call its status display methods. If you do not want an explicit dependency on Qt, then you might want to create a pure abstract `ProgressIndicator` interface class, make the file reading method use such a `ProgressIndicator` and then create a class, that inherits from `ProgressIndicator` and `QProgressBar` and connects the interface methods to the implementations in `QProgressBar`.